# how to refresh image in codenameone(netbeans)

Tags: css, image, mobile, netbeans, codenameone

Im creating the UI of my application from a PSD file following the instructions in: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/psd-to-app-revisited.html (by using the css support plugin), everything is fine, but i edited one of the images in photoshop and exported it again to my codenameone folder(replacing the original image) and i thought the new image would replace the original one, but the application is still showing the old image(it seems as it is cached or something similar).

I already tried "Clean and build project" but didnt worked, also went to the generated .res file and tried to delete the original image but it says i must first delete the themes that use them(which i dont want to do). Is there any way to "refresh" the images referenced in the .res file so they reflect the latest image in the folder? or a "clear cache" or something similar. For now i renamed the image, and also changed the name in the css,but i think is not the best way cause that implies creating new names for your images, and editing your css with every little change.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the image directly in the file system you need to do this when the designer is closed. Then reopen the designer res file and save it so the image is updated.

Comment: Thanks, in fact i did it even with the IDE closed and didnt worked but what i tried now(and worked) is  that if i delete the res file, when its regenerated from the css  the image is updated so my workflow now consists on deleting the res file->copy the new file to the directory->regenerate .res from .css